# Two identical pieces of jQuery behaving differently

Tags: php, jquery, string, forms

I have a PHP loop that outputs a bunch of links, then each link has a `href='javascript:$(\"#rnn\").val(" . $foo . ");$(\"#rnnNotifUnsub\").submit();'`

What is it supposed to do is to pass a certain piece of info pertaining to *that* link, over to a hidden input in #rnnNotifUnsub. However, it doesn't even submit when I try it out. I tried running the code without passing the variable to the hidden input and it submitted but of course didn't do anything. That means my problem lies in `$(\"#rnn\").val(" . $foo . ");` messing up the code.

Here's my form, just in case:

```
<form action="php/retailerNameNotifUnsub.php" id="rnnNotifUnsub" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="retailerName" id="rnn"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php print(selfURL()); ?>" name="url"/>
</form>
```

I have an identical set of code for an identical form, just with different names, and that works perfectly. Although that passes a int as a variable rather than a string to the hidden input. Perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: If two "identical" things are behaving different, then they are not really *identical* then are they?

Answer (score 2):

if foo is a string you will need to escape to set the value correctly.

From:

```
$(\"#rnn\").val(" . $foo . ");
```

To:

```
$(\"#rnn\").val(\"" . $foo . "\");
```

Comment: I tried that, but I'm having more escaping problem, because if I add the first single quote you added, it closes off a block of text (I'm echoing this all from PHP, so I start out with single quotes). Is there a way to escape these single quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Inline Javascript is a Bad Idea.  It is hard to maintain and messy.

I would give your links a `data-retailer` attribute and a class (I'll use `retailer`).  You could then use jQuery in a `script` tag like the following.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.retailer').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#rnn').val($(this).data('retailer'));
        $('#rnnNotifUnsub').submit();
    });
});
```

Example link:

```
<a class="retailer" data-retailer="Some Name" href="#">Content</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using " to print ( echo "hello world" ), Mark is right... Or...

```
href='javascript:$(\"#rnn\").val(\"" . $foo . "\");$(\"#rnnNotifUnsub\").submit();'
```